Total Number of Sonnet Types (Deceptively Complex)
How many sonnet types are there?

Sonnet here is: fourteen lines and each must rhyme.
Operationally, that means a fourteen-item series, with each element occurring not less than twice AND separated by two or fewer other elements.

Anciently, I knew a little math. Not so much now. This combinatorial(?) problem seems to require starting with 14! and cutting a pattern out of it.
Some examples, with capital letters to stand for the items in the series (and as capital letters are also used to stand for rhymed lines):
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ABABABABABABAB - NOTE: This should be regarded the same as BABABABABABABA.
AABABABABABABA
AAABABABABABAB
ABBAAAAAAAAAAA
AABBAAAAAAAAAA
AAABBAAAAAAAAA
Examples of what doesn't count
ABBBAAAAAAAAAA - Too many intervening items.
ABCAAAAAAAAAAA - C is without a matching element.
I thought I had a chunk done by reasoning as immediately below, but there was a problem.
--Break the problem in to three parts. a.) with no intervening items between matching items + b.) with one intervening item + c.) with two intervening items. Now with no intervening items that's something like AABBCCDDEEFFGG, so I could just consider it seven pairs, or 7!, right? No, because AABBBCCCCDDDDD would count as no intervening items, i.e. no ABA stuff. And that's more than 7! for sure.
***I would be happy if the answer here still leaves a bit of brute force to be done, e.g. "Here, do the plug-and-chug for these sixty equations and add the result." I'm not trying to escape work, just get over the hump where my expertise ends.
thank you!

Although I'm fine assuming it for the sake of the problem, I disagree that "separated by two or fewer other elements" is a hard barrier on rhyme scheme. The Charge of the Light Brigade is an example of a famous poem that routinely exceeds this.

[Charge] = confounded example. 1. Diff, meter (triple v. double) and 2. shorter lines. For sonnets, assume iambic pentameter (double). ALSO visually seeing isn't same as hearing: too much distance and the listener cannot hear it. But cool thoughts to keep in mind.

I suppose ABBABBBBBBCBBC is a sonnet. What if the C lines rhyme with the A lines? Then you have ABBABBBBBBABBA. There are more than two Bs between the second and third A, but every A is near another A separated by no more than two other lines. Is that a sonnet? Is it a form of sonnet distinct from ABBABBBBBBCBBC where C does not rhyme with A?

I cannot think of a solution better than brute force, so I made a Python program which is essentially brute force. I found that there were exactly $306\,264$ rhyme schemes with $14$ stanzas satisfying your rules. Here is a text document with the entire list I found: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BkM_9zl7xkh6UGzwt5lmGqwHbNqbIvHw/view?usp=sharing.
Instead of sharing my code, I will describe my method in English. A sonnet is represented as a list of positive integers. To ensure uniqueness, the first number of the sonnet is always $1$, and as you read from left to right, each number is at most one more than the largest number seen before then. The algorithm maintains a stack of partially filled sonnets. Initially, we only have the empty sonnet. As long as some incomplete sonnet remains, the algorithm removes an incomplete sonnet from the stack, then fills in the leftmost empty entry in all possible ways, then adds all these new partially completed sonnets to the stack.
I will refer to the leftmost empty entry of a partial sonnet as the current entry. Here are all of the possible ways of filling the current entry:

You can fill the current entry with any of the three previous entries.

You can fill the current entry with any number $k$ which is at most one more then the largest entry seen so far. In the case where $k$ is not equal to one of the earlier three entries, you must also put a number $k$ into one of the next three entries, to ensure the current entry is not isolated.


Each time a sonnet is completed, it is added to a collection. Since my algorithm will produce the same sonnet multiple times, this collection needs to be sorted and de-duped.

@DanielKemper I am not 100% confident my program is correct, but I am pretty confident. Here is a link where I uploaded the complete list of patterns I found, so you can compare my answer against the results from other methods: https://pastebin.com/U3kDGVkr

:-( Spot check: Petrarchan format ABBAABBACDECDE found nothing. Tried copying a pattern, changing one letter. Also not found.  AABABABCBCBBDB ( AABABABCBCBBDD exists - searched a known string to validate search technique. (Notepad++) Digging more to try to abstract a pattern out of it.

Mistake. second pattern above not valid. no d match. but French patterns not found either ABABCDCDGGEFEF and ABABCDCDGGEFFE.

Patterns that don't seem to be there:A B B A A B B A C D E C D E
A B A B C D C D G G E F F E
A B A B C D C D G G E F E F
A A B A B A B C B C B B D B
A B A B C B C D C D E D F F
A A B A B A B C B C D B D B
A A B A B A C C D B D B A A

Thank you for your great feedback. I have completely overhauled my list and am now getting a much larger number. There are certainly no repeats, and every sonnet in the list is legal, but I cannot be 100% sure I got them all.

Re: your last comment:
ABBAABBACDECDE now appears in my list.
ABABCDCDGGEFFE is equivalent to ABABCDCDEEFGGF, and the latter appears in my list.
ABABCDCDGGEFEF is equivalent to ABABCDCDEEFGFG, and the latter appears in my list.
AABABABCBCBBDB is illegal, as the D is isolated.
ABABCBCDCDEDFF is illegal, as the E is isolated.
AABABABCBCDBDB now appears in my list.
AABABACCDBDBAA now appears in my list.

MIke- getting prompted to move this to chat. Haven't done that before. Would that be o.k. Also, great note on equivalency. Good catches on my errors. The illegal E one could be changed to ...FDFF (It's a variant of the terza rima sonnet.) Let me know when I can get the next list to play with. :-)

I moved the comments to chat, here is the link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155500/discussion-between-mike-earnest-and-daniel-kemper

@DanielKemper So, is there any part of your question which is unanswered? If my answer resolves your issue, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Sorry for the vast delay.

One more quick permutation request if I may: What does the number become under the each of these conditions. A. No more than two identical letters in a row. (ABBA... is o.k., but ABBBA is not.) B. no more than three identical letters in a row. (ABBBA is o.k. but ABBBBA is not.

I found there were $165{,}995$ sonnets with at most two identical letters in a row, and $262{,}065$ sonnets with at most three identical letters in a row.

Thank you, Mike. You are the best. Are there any additional checkboxes or feedback or whatever I can check, etc. ?
